# Getting the value of a select list using jQuery

Tags: jquery, select, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

This is a problem I face while using jQuery within Firefox Jetpack. In my Jetpack code I'm dynamically creating some SELECT boxes with options and their
respective values:

```
...
listOfWords[i] = "<select id=clozefox_answer> <option
value=wrongAnswer>distractor</option>"
listOfWords[i] += "<option value=trueAnswer>" + currentWord +
"</option></select>"
...
textStr = listOfWords.join(" ");
$(this).html(textStr);
```

This works fine. Now after user makes some selections using the pull-down select lists on the page and clicks on the Calculate Score button I run a function to traverse the SELECT boxes and get their selected values:

```
$(doc).find("select[id=clozefox_answer]").each(function (index) {
   var selectedValue = $(this).val();

   if (selectedValue == "trueAnswer") {
       numCorrectAnswer++;
   }
});
```

Even though the above code correctly matched my dynamically created SELECTs, `$(this).val()` does NOT return the option value but the option text (e.g. "distractor" or whatever the variable **currentWord** included). How can I get the option value (e.g. "trueAnswer" or "wrongAnswer")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code does what I expect:

```
var selectedValue = $(this).attr("value");
```

But I still don't know why

```
var selectedValue = $(this).val();
```

does not work as expected. Anyway, I have solved my problem for now.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting quotes around all of your HTML attributes, this is standard practice.

Also, in your `find` selector you should put quotes around `clozefox_answer` and `id` ( `['id'='clozefox_answer']` )

If that doesn't work, then try getting the value by calling `$( this ).attr( 'value' );`

Comment: I have changed the relevant parts of the code as you said but still the same problem, $(this).val() is returning the option text instead of option value:

    listOfWords[i] = "<select id=\"clozefox_answer\"> <option value=\"wrongAnswer\">distractor</option>" 
    listOfWords[i] += "<option value=t\"trueAnswer\">" + currentWord + "</option></select>";

...

    $(doc).find("select[id='clozefox_answer']").each(function (index) {
 var selectedValue = $(this).val();

 if (selectedValue == "trueAnswer") {
     numCorrectAnswer++;
 } 
    });